# How to add REST API Client to .NET Core Console App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, swagger, .net-core, rest-client

When I right click UWP project in solution explorer, I see `Add -> REST API Client` context menu item.

[image: screenshot]

However, I don't see it in .NET Core Console Application

How do I generate REST Client code from swagger json so it can be used in .NET Core projects? Which tool is using Visual Studio? I don't mind using command line

Answer (score 0):

I use postman api to generate C# code.